# How to evaluate the trace of a product of sums of gamma matrices

Tags: evaluation

I have a large expression of a sum of gamma matrices which resulted from using [Casimir's Trick](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimirs_Trick#Details). It is quite tedious to evaluate so I thought about using Mathematica. However, I have no idea how, especially, when the contraction of Lorentz indices is involved.

I'm looking to evaluate an expression of the following form:

$(\gamma^\mu \moveright 6pt /p_a \gamma^\nu + \gamma^0 \moveright 6pt / p_b \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu)(\gamma_\nu +p_\nu)(\moveright 6pt / p_c+m)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FeynCalc ( I leave out the \gamma^0, but you could add GA[0] ):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/master/\
install.m"]
InstallFeynCalc[]

TR[(GA[\[Mu]].GS[Subscript[p, a]].GA[\[Nu]] + 
    GS[Subscript[p, b]].GA[\[Nu]].GA[\[Mu]]).(GA[\[Nu]] + 
    FV[p, \[Nu]]).(GS[Subscript[p, c]] + m)]
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Ah, wow. That is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. There is a slight potential problem: After installation of the current stable FeynCalc version you will see all output cells having `TraditionalForm`. You can reset this by `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {CommonDefaultFormatTypes, 
   "Output"}] = StandardForm`. I was too lazy to fix it  myself, but at least added an [issue](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/issues/30).